# Why can't I modify my entity without persist his attribute?

Tags: jpa

I have created a jpa entity named Mail, which have two foreign key.

```
public class Mail implements Serializable {


@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

@JoinColumn(name = "auteur")
private User user;

@JoinColumn(name = "typeC")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Type typeMail;
....
```

and when I want to modify a mail, I do like this:

```
public void modifyMail(Mail mail) {
  Mail m = em.find(Mail.class, mail.getId());
  m.setUser(mail.getUser());
  m.setType(mail.getType());
  em.persist(m);
}
```

but it doesn't work. In the glassfich logs, "em.persist" work correctly but glassfich also indicate an insertion in the User table; in the table User, the name is unique, so it don't work and I don't know why glassfich try to create the user associate to the mail. If somebody knows why please can he tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity manager keeps track of all objects/instances which you got from it. So if you use `em.find()` to load a user, it will know about this user instance.

If you keep user instances around after closing the transaction which you used to load them, they become stale. The entity manager doesn't really know about them anymore and assumes that they are new.

So the code above needs to be:

```
public void modifyMail(Mail mail) {
  Mail m = em.find(Mail.class, mail.getId());
  User u = em.find(User.class, mail.getUser().getId());
  m.setUser(u);
  m.setType(mail.getType());
  em.persist(m);
}
```

or

```
public void modifyMail(Mail mail) {
  Mail m = em.find(Mail.class, mail.getId());
  User u = em.refresh(mail.getUser());
  m.setUser(u);
  m.setType(mail.getType());
  em.persist(m);
}
```

The reason for this is that the entity manager doesn't know what "user" or "mail" means. All objects are the same for it. So if you change a user somewhere, the user instance in the `Mail` could be out of date.

But a better way is probably to change the code when the `Mail` instance is actually changed:

```
  em.getTransaction().begin();

  Mail mail = em.find(Mail.class, id);
  User u = em.find(User.class, userId);
  mail.setUser(u);

  em.getTransaction().end();
```

So instead of collecting changes, start the transaction, load all objects involved from the EM, make the changes and commit the transaction.

Comment: and you could add that "em.persist" is not needed, because if an object is "managed" then any updates to fields will be intercepted.

Comment: @BillyFrost: Really? I never tried this; I assumed that I need to "commit" changes to objects (and every example I saw would eventually call `persist()`). But it seems you're right: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/update

Comment: Thank you very much I try the first code Aaron gives and It works.